# How to copy a file to other directory sort by first received using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have some file in a folder, I want to copy one file which is the first received.

```
$Sel_JobFolder = "D:\Testing"
$PickJob = Get-ChildItem -Path "$Sel_JobFolder\*.que" | Sort-Object LastWriteTime
$count = 1
$GetJob = Get-Random -InputObject $PickJob -Count $count
Write-Output "Selected Job: $GetJob"
```

copy-Item $GetJob -Destination "C:\File"

#### Updated

This what I need, and It works

```
$PickJobs = @(Get-ChildItem "$Sel_JobFolder\*.que" | Sort LastWriteTime)[0] | % { Copy-Item -path $_.FullName -destination $("C:\Process") -force}
```

Comment: **_please_** edit your question to ask ONE THING or ONE COMBO OF THINGS. you cannot have `random` and `1st rcvd` ... those are mutually exclusive. [*grin*]

Comment: I edited. My goal is I want to sort the file by first received, then pick the file one by one start from the first received @Lee_Dailey

Comment: thank you for fixing that! it was quite confusing ... [*grin*] ///// please take a look at my answer - it seems to do what you were wanting done.

Comment: Hi @Lee_Dailey, thanks for your advice. But I still can not figure it out if my next process after I sort it, I want to copy the file ( only 1 file which is the first received)

Comment: Hi @Lee_Dailey I updated my question. I think this is what I need.

Comment: ah! so you only wanted the single newest ... not all the files in newest 1st order.  i misunderstood your request ... [*blush*]

Answer (score 1):

here's a very simple demo of how to work with a list of files in newest-first order. [*grin*]

```
$SourceDir = $env:TEMP
$Filter = '*.log'

$FileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDir -Filter $Filter -File |
    Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending

foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList)
    {
    'doing stuff to the files in newest-first order ...'
    '    {0}' -f $FL_Item.Name
    '    {0}' -f $FL_Item.LastWriteTime
    '=' * 50
    }
```

truncated output ...

```
doing stuff to the files in newest-first order ...
    Itunes_AlbumAutoRating_Disable.ps1_2019-08-19.log
    2019-08-19 12:21:25 PM
==================================================
doing stuff to the files in newest-first order ...
    Itunes_Default-Rating_Set.ps1_2019-08-16.log
    2019-08-16 12:47:38 PM
==================================================

[*...snip...*] 

==================================================
doing stuff to the files in newest-first order ...
    Grouping-Strings-List_2019-07-31.log
    2019-07-31 12:35:17 PM
==================================================
doing stuff to the files in newest-first order ...
    Itunes_Genre-Cleanup.ps1_2019-07-30.log
    2019-07-30 12:36:03 PM
==================================================
doing stuff to the files in newest-first order ...
    Genre-List_2019-07-30.log
    2019-07-30 12:36:03 PM
==================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it random or first received?

If it's a random, try using **get-random** from array ,

```
A, b, c | get-random -count 1
```

So your first scope is to create the array of the *pool* to be picked by the random function.

For the second option,

Your code is fine, but you need to sort it.

Or simply combine them both as per your need.

- **EDIT**

Try to modify the second line to :

```
$PickJob = (Get-ChildItem -Path "$Sel_JobFolder\*.que" | Select-Object -Property name,LastWriteTime) | Sort-Object LastWriteTime
```

Comment: I updated my question, actually I dont need to do random, I want to pick the file one by one sort by the first received.@Mahmood